# $CLASSPATH on ubuntu 12.4

Tags: mysql, linux, jdbc

command

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql.jar
```

This sets the class path for terminal. If I close that terminal window and start a new terminal window, I currently have to fire command to set class path. I want to set it so it's permanent. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Set it in the bash file. It is found in /$HOME/.bashrc or /$HOME/.bash_profile

Put that line there:

```
//for all users
nano ~/.bashrc 

//for current user 
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add that line and do CTRL + O to save and CTRL + X to exit
Or just use your text editor to open the file

Comment: your home path might be different. Do echo $HOME to see what the path is. I updated my answer

Comment: i used nano ~/.bash_profile for currnt profile but doesnt work.

Comment: You have to close your shell and reopen it for it to work. or do 
source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: ~/.bash_profile output is bash: /home/mayur/.bash_profile: Permission denied

Comment: Yes. after adding the export line to the .bash_profile of course. You should accept answer once it works

Comment: Well, that's a different question.  But thats how you export. At this point try using bashrc instead or post the error message you are receiving as a different question

Comment: output for ~/.bashrc is bash: /home/(User Name)/.bashrc: Permission denied

Comment: You have to be root user. prepend 'sudo' to any command to execute as root. For more help see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/ In your case the pathi CLASSPATH and shell is bash